# What is the essential difference between the two functions to find the first negative entry?

Tags: ocaml

From *Real World Ocaml*, page 24 (see https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/a-guided-tour.html#for-and-while-loops). The code is:

```
# let find_first_negative_entry array =
     let pos = ref 0 in
     while !pos < Array.length array && array.(!pos) >= 0 do
       pos := !pos + 1
     done;
     if !pos = Array.length array then None else Some !pos
  ;;
val find_first_negative_entry : int array -> int option = <fun>
# find_first_negative_entry [|1;2;0;3|];;
- : int option = None
# find_first_negative_entry [|1;-2;0;3|];;
- : int option = Some 1
```

and

```
# let find_first_negative_entry array =
     let pos = ref 0 in
     while
       let pos_is_good = !pos < Array.length array in
       let element_is_non_negative = array.(!pos) >= 0 in
       pos_is_good && element_is_non_negative
     do
       pos := !pos + 1
     done;
     if !pos = Array.length array then None else Some !pos
  ;;
val find_first_negative_entry : int array -> int option = <fun>
# find_first_negative_entry [|1;2;0;3|];;
Exception: (Invalid_argument "index out of bounds").
```

The authors claimed that:

> As a side note, the preceding code takes advantage of the fact that
>   &&, OCaml's And operator, short-circuits. In particular, in an
>   expression of the form expr1 && expr2, expr2 will only be evaluated if
>   expr1 evaluated to true. Were it not for that, then the preceding
>   function would result in an out-of-bounds error. Indeed, we can
>   trigger that out-of-bounds error by rewriting the function to avoid
>   the short-circuiting:"

But I still do not really understand why the first code works fine, and the second get the exception. I complied and both function behave as expected. But I am very puzzled why the second function does not work, since it used the && command as well, and it handled no negative entry with None exception as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the order of evaluation.  In the first function `Term1 && Term2` allows `&&` short circuit behavior to protect us from Term2.  In the second example the let bindings are always evaluated before the test occurs.  Therefore there is no protection from Term2's bad behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In the first version if `!pos >= Array.length array` then `!pos < Array.length array && whatever` must be true regardless of the value of `whatever`, that's why OCaml won't compute `whatever`. In our case, `array.(!pos) >= 0` would raise an error if evaluated when `!pos >= Array.length array`.

In the second version however, `array.(!pos) >= 0` is always evaluated, even if `array.(!pos) >= 0` which produces an error.

Comment: Thanks, I need to think about it.

Comment: I read the code, but I could not get your answer. You suggested if !pos>= Array.length array then the later would be true, but isn't this implies the later is false? Similarly I could not get the second part.